# Is there a way to run code using caffe from the caffe ssd tree using Windows?

Tags: windows, caffe, pycaffe

I recently installed the [windows branch](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) of Caffe onto my windows machine. It works fine but then we I tried running some other projects I found online they didn't work at all and gave me all kinds of errors.

I think the reason it doesn't work is because they were using a different branch of caffe, [this one](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) for instance.

Is there a fix to this problem? Can I run ssd caffe on windows somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The Caffe-SSD is not a branch, but a fork of the vanilla Caffe. Compiling and using Caffe on Windows requires certain effort (e.g. pre-building some external libs, adjusting CMake config etc.), which was not done for the Caffe-SSD fork.

You need to merge the contributions from the Windows branch into the Caffe-SSD. There are some existing solutions for that (https://github.com/runhang/caffe-ssd-windows, https://github.com/gustavkkk/caffe-ssd-win, google for more), but I did not use those.